# how to calculate x,y and z values from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, echarts

I have json data format given below. From this data I need to display group11 emotions only in 3D charts.So i need x ,y and z value.how to get these values please give me some logic.we can use anything from this given json.

## JSON

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "result": {
    "duration": "15034.88",
    "sessionStatus": "Done",
    "analysisSegments": [
      {
        "offset": 0,
        "duration": 10000,
        "end": 10000,
        "analysis": {
          "Temper": {
            "Value": "62.00",
            "Group": "medium",
            "Score": "59.00"
          },
          "Valence": {
            "Value": "96.00",
            "Group": "positive",
            "Score": "94.00"
          },
          "Arousal": {
            "Value": "98.00",
            "Group": "high",
            "Score": "97.00"
          },
          "Vad": {
            "Voiced": "70.00"
          },
          "Mood": {
            "Group7": {
              "Primary": {
                "Id": 1,
                "Phrase": "Angry"
              },
              "Secondary": {
                "Id": 3,
                "Phrase": "Enthusiastic"
              }
            },
            "Group11": {
              "Primary": {
                "Id": 11,
                "Phrase": "Supremacy, Arrogance"
              },
              "Secondary": {
                "Id": 1,
                "Phrase": "Creative, Passionate"
              }
            },
            "Group21": {
              "Primary": {
                "Id": 9,
                "Phrase": "egoism"
              },
              "Secondary": {
                "Id": 18,
                "Phrase": "motivation"
              }
            },
            "Composite": {
              "Primary": {
                "Id": 143,
                "Phrase": "Insistence and stubbornness. Possibly childishness."
              },
              "Secondary": {
                "Id": 5,
                "Phrase": "Ambitious. Assertiveness to achieve goals."
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "offset": 5000,
        "duration": 10000,
        "end": 15000,
        "analysis": {
          "Temper": {
            "Value": "63.00",
            "Group": "medium",
            "Score": "57.00"
          },
          "Valence": {
            "Value": "89.00",
            "Group": "positive",
            "Score": "84.00"
          },
          "Arousal": {
            "Value": "94.00",
            "Group": "high",
            "Score": "91.00"
          },
          "Vad": {
            "Voiced": "62.00"
          },
          "Mood": {
            "Group7": {
              "Primary": {
                "Id": 1,
                "Phrase": "Angry"
              },
              "Secondary": {
                "Id": 3,
                "Phrase": "Enthusiastic"
              }
            },
            "Group11": {
              "Primary": {
                "Id": 11,
                "Phrase": "Supremacy, Arrogance"
              },
              "Secondary": {
                "Id": 6,
                "Phrase": "Leadership, Charisma"
              }
            },
            "Group21": {
              "Primary": {
                "Id": 8,
                "Phrase": "dominance"
              },
              "Secondary": {
                "Id": 18,
                "Phrase": "motivation"
              }
            },
            "Composite": {
              "Primary": {
                "Id": 107,
                "Phrase": "Possessiveness. Ownership. Authoritative."
              },
              "Secondary": {
                "Id": 41,
                "Phrase": "Strong drive."
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "analysisSummary": {
      "AnalysisResult": {
        "Temper": {
          "Mode": "medium",
          "ModePct": "100.00"
        },
        "Valence": {
          "Mode": "positive",
          "ModePct": "100.00"
        },
        "Arousal": {
          "Mode": "high",
          "ModePct": "100.00"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## What I have tried

1. x-Emotion name(Supremacy, Arrogance)
2. y-Emotion count(how many times repeated)
3. z-Emotion duration(in minutes)

## json parse

```
var counter4=0;
var val4 =0;
var val4minute =0;
   var phrase = rawdata[i]["analysis"]["Mood"]["Group11"]["Primary"]["Phrase"];
      if (phrase == "Supremacy, Arrogance") {
  counter4++;
 val4 = counter4 * 10000;
 val4minute = Math.floor(val4 / 60000);
}
```

Here x is "Supremacy, Arrogance" counter4 is y axis and val4minute  is z axis

but this logic is wrong can any one give me a better logic.

Comment: step 1 - don't use JSON directly, parse it using JSON.parse to an object, far easier to work with than a string

Comment: yes parsed.to post the json for better to understand to all.

Comment: while displaying 2d charts x is emotion name and y is emotion count,but 3d charts means need z value also how to get it?

Comment: @ Jaromanda can you check it now i added my Javascript logic